# Convenience macro to select union member matching value type

Tags: c

I have a union type declared as follows:

```
typedef union Data {
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;
    float f;
} data;
```

I know fields are overwritten by new values. I would like to know if there is any way to do the following instead of needing to manually access each field depending on the type of data I want to store:

```
    data *c;
    *c = 3;  // instead of c.i = 3; c.i should be 3
    *c = 'a' // instead of c.c = 'a'; c.c should be 'a', c.i should no longer be 3;
```

I tried doing as written above, but I get an error saying:

```
Assigning to 'data' (aka 'union Data') from incompatible type 'int'.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The language isn't designed as such. You'd better give up trying to "invent" new syntaxes.

Comment: @Haris I'm not fluent in C, why is that, I'm assuming obviously, not correct?

Comment: what if there are multiple fields of the same type or length? And what if the value matches multiple fields in the union? Both `'a'` and 3 are `int` in C, and both also fit in a `char`

Comment: It appears that you are trying to create "variant" - a type of variable that can have any type. These are widely recognized as bad practice to avoid, since they are both slow and memory consuming, for no good reason. So don't do this, I have yet to see a valid use case for "variants". Good programs are deterministic and that includes choice of types.

Comment: Also `data* c; *c = ...` is an obvious bug regardless of which member you want to access. You haven't allocated any memory for storing data, all you have is an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach with a tagged union and a polymorphic instantiation macro.  Note however that `'a'` has type `int` in C and `char` in C++, so it must be cast as `(char)'a'` to have type `char` in both languages.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    enum { CHAR, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE } type;
    union {
        char   c;
        int    i;
        float  f;
        double d;
    };
} data;

#define data(v) _Generic((v),   \
    char:   (data){ .type = CHAR,   .c = (v) }, \
    int:    (data){ .type = INT,    .i = (v) }, \
    float:  (data){ .type = FLOAT,  .f = (v) }, \
    double: (data){ .type = DOUBLE, .d = (v) })

void print(data x) {
    switch (x.type) {
    case CHAR:   printf("char:  '%c'\n", x.c); break;
    case INT:    printf("int:    %d\n", x.i); break;
    case FLOAT:  printf("float:  %gf\n", (double)x.f); break;
    case DOUBLE: printf("double: %g\n", x.d); break;
    }
}

int main() {
    data a = data((char)'a');  // char
    data b = data('a');        // int
    data c = data(3);          // int
    data d = data(1.2f);       // float
    data e = data(3.14);       // double
    print(a);
    print(b);
    print(c);
    print(d);
    print(e);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
char:  'a'
int:    97
int:    3
float:  1.2f
double: 3.14
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  It's not possible.  If you want type switching use _Generic but 'a' is an integer character constant (i.e. type is `int`) so you will only find partial success with sample input provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    char c;
    double d;
    float f;
    int i;
} data;

#define set(d, v) _Generic((v),\
    char: setc,\
    double: setd,\
    float: setf,\
    int: seti\
)((d), (v))

void setc(data d, int v) {
    d.c = v;
    printf("c = %c\n", d.c);
}

void setd(data d, double v) {
    d.d = v;
    printf("d = %lf\n", d.d);
}

void seti(data d, int v) {
    d.i = v;
    printf("i = %d\n", d.i);
}

void setf(data d, float f) {
    d.f = f;
    printf("f = %f\n", d.f);
}

int main() {
    data d = { 0 };
    set(d, 'a'); // seti()
    set(d, (char) 'c');
    set(d, 3.14);
    set(d, 1.2f);
    set(d, 3);
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
i = 97
c = c
d = 3.140000
f = 1.200000
i = 3
```

Comment: It is better to write the `_Generic` as `(_Generic((v), char: (d).c,…) = (v))` than `_Generic((v), char: d.c = v,…)`. With the form you have, the individual assignments `d.c = v`, `d.d = v`, and so on are all parsed by the compiler even though only one is selected. Then, if there is anything in them that may cause a warning (like assigning `3.4` to an `int` with precision warnings enabled) or an error (like assign an `int` to a member that is a structure, if we add a structure member to the union), you will get a compiler message. The former form has only one assignment, matching the value.

Comment: Is it possible to also set a flag indication which field is set? Cause that's useless as-is.

Comment: Also, as usual with macros, put the parameter in parentheses, both `d` and `v`, and then, since the form I propose is an assignment rather than a primary expression, enclose it in parentheses as well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks.  I already had a revision in progress to use wrapper functions to demonstrate the char version isn't called.

Comment: If OP is content to write `set(d, (char) 'a')` rather than `set(d, 'a')`, this will work. Particularly if their posted code is just for demonstration and the actual use would set values from variables rather than constants.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, it is possible to make it a tagged union.  Op asked about a regular union and it's not "useless".

Comment: @EricPostpischil Revised as suggested, thanks.

Comment: Re "*It's not "useless"*", Yes it is. There's no point to autodetecting the type if you still have to specify it manually. It gains you absolutely nothing. And that's the very definition of useless. /// Re "*Op asked about a regular union*", Yes, I know the OP made that error. But you didn't address it.

Comment: @ikegami Let's disagree then.  Sometimes a union like this is misused for type conversion, or user may track state elsewhere.

Comment: You just repeated what I said, so how is that disagreeing? Like I said, and like you just repeated, you still have to "track" (specify) the type. So this doesn't help at all. There's no advantage to doing `type = TYPE_DOUBLE; set(val, x)` over `type = TYPE_DOUBLE; val.d = x;`. It literally only works for a single type.

Comment: You just repeated what I said, so how is that disagreeing? Like I said, and like you just repeated, you still have to "track" (specify) the type. So this doesn't help at all. There's no advantage to doing `doube x = ...; type = TYPE_DOUBLE; set(val, x)` over `double x = ...; type = TYPE_DOUBLE; val.d = x;.` It literally only works for a single type. (And it's error prone!) It's only if `set` also sets the type enum (whether internal or external) that it might become useful.

Comment: @chqrlie I could not get clang or gcc to generate a warning for it.

Comment: Indeed, it is a compound literal. My bad.